# CONCAT with GROUP_CONCAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-concat, concatenation

So I have looked everywhere for an answer to this, but so far no luck. Any help is much appreciated. I am new to mysql (transferring from a filemaker pro background).

I have a database where I keep information for prospects for our business. I have a question about listing information for our users to see. The **INQUIRY table** holds the information for each inquiry (i.e. date inquiry came in, status of the inquiry, etc.). The **PROSPECT table** holds the information on each prospect (potential client) (i.e. first name, last name, age, etc.). A third **table, INQUIRYNOTES**, hold information on our contacts with the prospect (i.e. next contact date, notes, next action, etc.). Each of these tables are related with the key **inquiryID**.

Each day a user will come to a screen where they will be presented with the leads/inquiries that he/she will follow up on for that day which are those inquiries who's action date is less than or equal to today. I want the list to contain the **inquiryID**, **listed names of all prospects related to that inquiryID** (max 2), and the **action date**.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT inquiry.inquiryID,
   CASE WHEN prospect.lastName = '' THEN prospect.firstName
   WHEN prospect.firstName = '' THEN prospect.lastName
   ELSE CONCAT(prospect.lastName, ', ',prospect.firstName) END as fullName, inquiryNote.actionDate
FROM inquiry, prospect, inquiryNote
WHERE inquiry.inquiryID = prospect.inquiryID
AND inquiry.inquiryID = inquirynote.inquiryID
AND inquirynote.actionDate != \"0000-00-00\"
AND actionDate <= \"".date("Y-m-d")."\"
GROUP BY inquiryID ORDER BY actionDate";
```

This returns the information that I am looking for, but it only lists one of the prospect (even if there are 2 for the inquiry).

Next I tried putting the GROUP_CONCAT(firstname) in this and it gave me a list of the first names of the prospect listed in a row separated by commas (I'm getting closer). Then I tried GROUP_CONCAT(last name, ', ', firstname) and then GROUP_CONCAT(lastname,firstname), but again it would only list one prospect, not the multiple prospects separated by commas.

I want the variable that I named ***fullName*** in the code above to be included in the GROUP_CONCAT so that in the rows returned I see a list of all prospect related to an inquiry listed and divided by a comma.

I want the table in the webpage I have created to have these columns:

inquiryID **|** prospects name(s) (last name first) **|** Next Action Date

Again so far I can only seem to get:

inquiryID **|** 1 prospect name **|** Next Action Date

The solution could be something easy, but since I am new to mysql I am lost.

Please let me know if you need more detail.

---

UPDATE WITH SOLUTION, BUT SIMILAR QUESTION AT THE END

---

The problem was that some of the first name and last name fields had NULL values. Apparently, GROUP_CONCAT will now work with null values. This is the query that I ended with that worked once I got rid of all of the NULL values:

```
SELECT 
  inquiry.inquiryID, 
  inquiry.initialDate,
  inquiryNote.actionDate,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      CASE WHEN prospect.lastName = '' THEN prospect.firstName
      WHEN prospect.firstName = '' THEN prospect.lastName
       ELSE CONCAT(
        prospect.firstName, ' ',prospect.lastName
      ) END
    ) SEPARATOR ', '
  ) AS prospectList,

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      CASE WHEN influencer.lastName = '' THEN influencer.firstName
      WHEN influencer.firstName = '' THEN influencer.lastName
      ELSE CONCAT(
        influencer.firstName, ' ',influencer.lastName
      ) END
    ) SEPARATOR ', '
  ) AS influencerList

FROM inquiry, prospect, inquiryNote, influencer WHERE inquiry.inquiryID = prospect.inquiryID
AND inquiry.inquiryID = inquirynote.inquiryID
AND inquiry.inquiryID = influencer.inquiryID
AND inquirynote.actionDate != "0000-00-00" AND actionDate <= "2011-09-22"
GROUP BY inquiryID
ORDER BY actionDate;
```

**So the final question is, can I make GROUP_CONCAT work even when it encounters NULL values?**

Comment: Most likely you'd want `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(lastname, ', ', firstname))`

Answer (score 1):

You can COALESCE the columns in case the contain NULLs:

COALESCE(lastname, '') would return an empty string if lastname was null, or whatever the value of lastname is if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT simply ignores(skips) NULL values http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/mysql-the-group_concat-function/